# How to relate a table to other two?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm trying to design a database that contains, among others, entities "Photo", "Venues" and "Products".
Given both Venues and Products could contain a collection of photos... how could I tell whether the photo is from a Venue or a product?

```
Photos
    Id PK
    Venue_Id FK
    Product_Id FK

Venues
    ID PK
    Photos_Id FK

Products
    ID PK
    Photos_Id Fk
```

Comment: Wait, in the table `Venues` and `Products` there is 1 FK `Photos_Id`, Does it come from `Photos` table? You want to know if photo if from a `Venue` or a `Product`? Can you alter those tables? Maybe if you provide us more information we can build you a better design.

Comment: Is there a name for some superclass that includes both venues and products as subclasses?  There is a tag called subtypes that group together questions of that ilk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is likely something wrong with your model. Mutual dependencies are very rare in relational database designs. This is what I assume you want to do:

```
create table photos
( photo_id ... not null primary key
, <additional attributes> );

create table venues
( venue_id ... not null primary key
, photo_id ... not null
      references photos (photo_id) 
, <additional attributes> );

create table products
( product_id ... not null primary key
, photo_id ... not null
      references photos (photo_id) 
, <additional attributes> );
```

To determine whether a photo belongs to a venue, product or both you could do something like:

```
select x.photo_id
     , case when y.photo_id is not null then 'Venue' end
     , case when z.photo_id is not null then 'Product' end
from photos x
left join venues y
    on x.photo_id = y.photo_id
left join products z
    on x.photo_id = z.photo_id
```